# Double frequency buck converter - minimum values of smaller and larger inductances

Tags: circuit-design, dc-dc-converter, buck

Consider a double frequency buck converter shown below having small and large inductors operating at higher and lower switching frequencies respectively, in order to improve both the transient response and efficiency.

The overall converter behaviour is very similar to a single high frequency converter except for low switching losses now.

For a design problem, I want to know how do I come up with minimum values of smaller and larger inductances for given switching frequencies?

I know that % ripple current is the criteria to come up with minimum inductance, but this spec computes smaller or larger L for double frequency topology & how do I derive other one?

[image: Extract from: Double-frequency buck converter as a candidate topology for integrated envelope elimination and restoration applications in power supply of RFPAs.]

<sub>Source: Saberkari, A., Shirmohammadli, V., Martinez, H., and Alarcón, E. (2016) **Double-frequency buck converter as a candidate topology for integrated envelope elimination and restoration applications in power supply of RFPAs.** *Int. J. Circ. Theor. Appl.*, 44: 1156–1172. doi: [10.1002/cta.2155](https://doi.org/10.1002/cta.2155) ([author's final draft](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/81580593.pdf))</sub>

Comment: Dev - Hi, Please remember the [site rule](/help/referencing) which requires that when a post includes content (e.g. text, image, photo etc.) copied or adapted from elsewhere, that content must be correctly referenced. As a minimum, the source webpage or PDF etc. should be linked for online material (see the linked rule regarding books etc.). In order to help you, I found what I believe to be the source details & added them for you. For the future, please remember it's your responsibility to do that :) Thanks.

Comment: so, i'd say look at equation 11 and solve L for each branch with it's associated frequency